# BigQuery: Select entire repeated field with group

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using LegacySQL, but am not strictly limited to it. (though it does have some methods I find useful, "HASH" for example).

Anyhow, the simple task is that I want to group by one top level column, while still keeping the first instance of a nested+repeated set of data alongside.

So, the following "works", and produces nested output:

```
SELECT 
  cd,
  subarray.* 
FROM [magicalfairy.land]
```

And now I attempt to just grab the entire first subarray (honestly, I don't expect this to work of course)
The following is what doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
  cd,
  FIRST(subarray.*) 
FROM [magicalfairy.land]
GROUP BY cd
```

---

Any alternate approaches would be appreciated.

---

*Edit, for data behaviour example.*

If Input data was roughly:

```
[
    {
        "cd": "something",
        "subarray": [
            {
                "hello": 1,
                "world": 1
            },
            {
                "hello": 2,
                "world": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cd": "something",
        "subarray": [
            {
                "hello": 1,
                "world": 1
            },
            {
                "hello": 2,
                "world": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Would expect to get out:

```
[
    {
        "cd": "something",
        "subarray": [
            {
                "hello": 1,
                "world": 1
            },
            {
                "hello": 2,
                "world": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: what you expect to have as a result of second (in your question) query? what is "wrong" with first one? please elaborate as it is not clear what you expect

Comment: updated with example.

Comment: depends on your definition of "first array" - if you mean "any" - see solution below by @Elliott-Brossard - just use your table instead of T in his example; if you really need "first - you need to define what does it mean. you might have some extra column like timestamp which will define the order!

Comment: I do mean any, but I thought that ANY_VALUE went into an array and returned one value from it, or is it at the right level/context to know that it has a list of arrays and to return one of those entire arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have a much better time preserving the structure using standard SQL, e.g.:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT
    cd,
    ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y BOOL>>[
      STRUCT(off, MOD(off, 2) = 0),
      STRUCT(off - 1, false)] AS subarray
  FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 1, 2]) AS cd WITH OFFSET off)
SELECT
  cd,
  ANY_VALUE(subarray) AS subarray
FROM T
GROUP BY cd;
```

`ANY_VALUE` will return some value of `subarray` for each group. If you wanted to concatenate the arrays instead, you could use `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG`.

to run this against your table  - try below

```
SELECT
  cd,
  ANY_VALUE(subarray) AS subarray
FROM `magicalfairy.land`
GROUP BY cd
```

Comment: I only want the set of values from the first array that matches to a group. (the others can be thrown away)

Comment: That's what `ANY_VALUE` will do: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#any_value. Note that the `FIRST` aggregate function in legacy SQL is misleading, as there is no notion of the "first" value for a group.

Comment: For a set of arrays, I want the entirety of the first array.

Comment: *see my comments on the main question too, ANY does work, but I guess what I wanted to verify is that ANY_VALUE is receiving an array of arrays at this select context (not a flattened set of array elements from all the arrays).

Comment: That's what the query will do. Did you try running it? Compare the output to that of `SELECT * FROM T;`

Comment: I will be in a sec, I'm trying to decipher how much of your array notation and other pieces in that first select I actually need to use on my end.

Comment: You can ignore the `WITH` clause for your purposes; that was just to set up some sample nested repeated data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121289/discussion-between-casualt-and-elliott-brossard).

Comment: sorry, I went ahead and added query against actual table

Answer (score 1):

Try below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT cd, subarray 
FROM (
  SELECT cd, subarray, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cd) AS num
  FROM `magicalfairy.land`
) WHERE num = 1
```

This gives you expected result - equivalent of "ANY ARRAY"
This solution can be extended to "FIRST ARRAY" by adding `ORDER BY sort_col` into OVER() clause - assuming that sort_col defines the logical order